# Dynamic database parameters file on Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony and i'm trying to load different parameters.yml depending on host, including database configuration. So, in apache vhosts, I defined a variable that let me know what client is in PHP by $_SERVER["CLIENTID"] ( Directive SetEnv ). And now I want to, for example if CLIENTID is "client1", load parameters_client1.yml, that contains db_host, db_user, etc... 
I tried this way :

app/config/config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host:     "%db_host%"
        dbname:   "%db_name%"
        user:     "%db_user%"
        password: "%db_password%"
```

app/config/parameters_client1.yml

```
parameters:
    db_host: "localhost"
    db_name: "client1_database"
    db_user: "client1"
    db_password: "something"
```

src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('appbundle');
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $rootdir = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
        // Load the bundle's services.yml
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new         FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        // Load parameters depending on current host
        $paramLoader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($rootdir.'/config')); // Access the root config directory

        $parameters = "parameters.yml";

        if( array_key_exists("CLIENTID", $_SERVER) )
        {
            $paramfile = sprintf('parameters_%s.yml', $_SERVER["CLIENTID"]);
            if (file_exists($rootdir.'/config/'.$paramfile))
            {
                $parameters = $paramfile;
            }
        }

        $paramLoader->load($parameters);
    }
}
```

But that's not working, I got the following error :

```
ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 100:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "db_host".
```

Please can somebody explain me what I've missed ?
I'm using Symfony 3.2

Answer (score 1):

A rough guess are you including the resource in app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
```